# Connecting a variable in the main method with another method Java

Tags: java

The method should return true if the argument is even, or
false otherwise. The program’s main method should use a loop to generate 100 random integers. It should use the isEven method to determine whether each random number is even, or odd. All this is done!!!

This is the part where I can't figure it out!

When the loop is finished, the program should display the number of even numbers that were generated, and the number of odd numbers.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class EvenOdd
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Random random = new Random();

        int randomInteger = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            randomInteger = random.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Random Integer: " + randomInteger);
            EvenOdd(randomInteger);
        }
    }

    public static void EvenOdd(int x)
    {

        int oddNumbers = 0;
        int evenNumbers = 0;

        if ((x % 2) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Even");
            evenNumbers++;

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Odd");
            oddNumbers++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `evenNumbers` and `oddNumbers` are local to the `EvenOdd` method. Every time the code reaches `}` of this function, they no longer exist. Try defining them *out* of `EvenOdd` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Random random = new Random();

    int randomInteger = 0;
    int oddNumbers = 0;
    int evenNumbers = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        randomInteger = random.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Random Integer: " + randomInteger);
        if(evenOdd(randomInteger)) evenNumbers++;
        else oddNumbers++;
    }
    System.out.printf("Even numbers: %d - Odd numbers: %d", evenNumbers, oddNumbers);
}

public static boolean evenOdd(int x)
{
    if ((x % 2) == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Even");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Odd");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your original approach doesn't work because you initialize to 0 the `oddNumbers` and `evenNumbers` variables everytime you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Define  oddNumbers, evenNumbers variables as static class variables and after the loop you can print these 2 value.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not JavaScript. Also, it does not have the ability of C++ as "Static variables in functions".

Variables declared inside a method are local. Variables initialization occurs every time your code reaches a variable definition inside the method and destroyed after exiting from the method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

So you have such variants:

1) Count numbers inside your main method and return indicator from the utility method.

1.1) boolean

```
public static boolean isEven(int x){
    return (x % 2) == 0;
};
```

1.2) enum

```
private enum NumberType {
    EVEN,
    ODD
}

public static NumberType getNumberType (int x) {
    if ((x % 2) == 0) {
        return NumberType.EVEN;
    } else {
        return NumberType.ODD;
    }
};
```

2) Make your variables static:

```
public class EvenOdd {

    private static int evenNumbersCount = 0;
    private static int oddNumbersCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your code
    }

    public static void countNumberType (int x) {
        if ((x % 2) == 0) {
            ++evenNumbersCount;
        } else {
            ++oddNumbersCount;
        }
    }
}
```

3) In some sophisticated situations you will need to pass container to your method:

```
public class EvenOdd {

    private static final String EVEN = "even";
    private static final String ODD = "odd";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initialize container
        Map<String, Integer> evenOddCounts = new HashMap<>(2, 1);
        evenOddCounts.put(EVEN, 0);
        evenOddCounts.put(ODD, 0);

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomInteger = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            randomInteger = random.nextInt();
            countNumberType(evenOddCounts, randomInteger);
        }

        System.out.println(evenOddCounts.toString());
    }

    public static void countNumberType(Map<String, Integer> counts, int x) {
        if ((x % 2) == 0) {
            counts.compute(EVEN, (numberType, count) -> ++count);
        } else {
            counts.compute(ODD, (numberType, count) -> ++count);
        }
    }
}
```